# AngularJS DropDown disable document scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, dropdown

Currently using the angularjs dropdown, whenever I scroll to the end of each side of the content, I will be scrolling the body instead which is kinda annoying. 
Is there anyway to stop body document from scrolling when the dropdown is showing up?

Here's an example, when you click on Select item.. you could still scroll
http://jsfiddle.net/hAnGA/7/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <drop-down list="dropdown" current="category" group="groupone"></drop-down>    

    <br/><br/>

    {{ category | json }}

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your directive if the dropdown it's open and add a listener for scroll event like this:

```
if (scope.open) {                        
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  })            
}
```

Comment: Balaj, thanks for your answer. However currently I'm not able to detect the close of the scope, if they do select a value I could, but not for 'click outside'  event.

Comment: 2 minutes, I'm updating my answer

Comment: Thanks, sorry the fiddle example is not showing the exact situation of mine. 
In the fiddle it does not close the dropdown when there's a click outside event. I'll try to update that.

Comment: so you want to close the drop down when clicking outside? but also you want to stop the scroll on the body when the drop down is open?

Comment: Balaj, thanks for your help. I think I found the function. $scope.settings.closeOnBlur

Comment: cool, I was thinking to make an click-outside attribute directive which addeventlistener to body on click and set the scope.open to false, and also a listener to the element to event.stopPropagation();